# Why should we report Z when reporting the results of a Wilcoxon Signed Rank test?

Tags: wilcoxon-signed-rank, z-score

I read these [guidelines on how to report statistics in APA style](http://evc-cit.info/psych018/Reporting_Statistics.pdf) and it recommends to report the Z score when reporting the results of a Wilcoxon Signed Rank test. Why is it important to report the Z score for a Wilcoxon Signed Rank test? Just the p-value is not enough? If my sample is not normally distributed, does it still makes sense to compute the Z score?